# lambda handler to download file using bottle in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bottle

I am using **AWS** and **python + bottle** to download file.

The following code works fine and file download with out any problem in **local system**.

```
from bottle import route, run, template, response, HTTPResponse,static_file

@route('/static/<file_path:path>')
def static(file_path):
    return static_file(file_path, root='./static', mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                    download='exam.bin', charset='UTF-8')

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

But in **AWS** the following code does not work

```
from bottle import route, run, template, response, HTTPResponse,static_file
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return static_file(file_path, 
                       root='./static', 
                       mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                       download='exam.bin',
                       charset='UTF-8')
```

that give the following **error**:

> {
>     "errorMessage": "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"exam.bin\"\nContent-Length: 632\nLast-Modified: Thu, 01 Jun 2017 15:13:58 GMT\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\n is not JSON serializable",
>     "errorType": "TypeError"
>   }

Please help to solve this problem,..

Comment: You should be using Bottle /or/ Lambda, not both. You seem confused about how Lambda works. Don't use bottle in your Lambda.

Comment: @ron.rothman then how can download files from lambda handler